# R: Drop all not matching letters of string vector

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a string vector

`d <- c("sladfj0923rn2", ääas230ß0sadfn", 823Höl32basdflk")`

I want to remove all characters from this vector that do not
match "a-z", "A-z" and "'"

I tried to use 
`gsub("![a-zA-z'], "", d)`
 but that doesn't work.

Comment: I presume you mean `a-z` or `A-Z`, that is, capital or lowercase letters.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: I would need this:
d <- c("sladfjrn", "ääasßsadfn", "Hölbasdflk")
as there are certain German letters, I guess they would need to be added:
gsub("[^a-zäö?]", "", d, ignore.case=TRUE)

Answer (score 2):

We could even make your replacement pattern even tighter by doing a case insensitive `sub`:

```
d <- c("sladfj0923rn2", "ääas230ß0sadfn", "823Höl32basdflk")
gsub("[^a-z]", "", d, ignore.case=TRUE)

[1] "sladfjrn"  "assadfn"   "Hlbasdflk"
```

Comment: but you mean gsub("[^a-z]", "", d, ignore.case=TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `^` inside the square brackets to match all characters except the one specified within the bracket

```
gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", d)
#[1] "sladfjrn"  "assadfn"   "Hlbasdflk"
```

#### data

```
d <- c("sladfj0923rn2", "ääas230ß0sadfn", "823Höl32basdflk")
```

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi. I didn't understand your second pattern

Comment: Oh..sorry. Well in `d` there is no instance of '. But in general, I could add characters that I want to keep in the square.